# Jersey with embedded Jetty server

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to run Jersey REST service with embedded Jetty server. This is my resource class:

```
public class FileUploadService {

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail){

    String uploadedFileLocation = "/uploaded" + fileDetail.getFileName();
    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);
    String output = "File uploaded to: " + uploadedFileLocation;
    return Response.status(200)
                   .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:63342")
                   .allow("OPTIONS")
                   .build();


    }
}
```

I´ve also added main method with embedded server:

```
public class SimpleServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");

    Server jettyServer = new Server(4343);
    jettyServer.setHandler(context);

    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/*");
    jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

    // Tells the Jersey Servlet which REST service/class to load.
    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(
      "/",
       FileUploadService.class.getCanonicalName());

    try {
        jettyServer.start();
        jettyServer.join();
    } finally {
        jettyServer.destroy();
    }
}

}
```

I´ve added following dependencies to pom file:

```
<groupId>JAXRS-FileUpload</groupId>
<artifactId>JAXRS-FileUpload</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<properties>
    <java.source.level>1.7</java.source.level>
    <java.target.level>1.7</java.target.level>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.0.M0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.0.M0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.source.level}</source>
                <target>${java.target.level}</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>server.SimpleServer</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I built my project and installed dependencies using maven command:

```
mvn clean package install
```

After the execution of the command I run server with the following command:

```
java -jar JAXRS-FileUpload-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I am getting the following output on the console:

```
2014-11-09 00:16:18.011:INFO::main: Logging initialized @83ms
2014-11-09 00:16:18.067:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
2014-11-09 00:16:18.641:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started   o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2e8e96cd{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2014-11-09 00:16:18.653:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@54e0a229{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4343}
2014-11-09 00:16:18.653:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @727ms
```

But when I try to access my app from web browser I am getting the following error message:

```
HTTP ERROR: 404

Problem accessing /. Reason:

Not Found
```

Comment: Pls add web.xml and the url you are trying to access to

Comment: I am trying to access localhost:4343 and localhost:4343/upload. I am missing web.xml

Answer (score 3):

add your `FileUploadService` class to a package  (e.g. `com.your.package.name`) and then try the following (you can omit the full classnames in your code, they are only here for clarity):

```
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig() {{
        packages("com.your.package.name");
    }};
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer container = new ServletContainer(rc);
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(container);
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/foo");
    context.addServlet(holder, "/bar");
```

All resources in `com.your.package.name` should be available on `http://<host>/foo/bar`

Tested with jetty 9.1.3.v20140225 and jersey 2.7

Comment: I am still getting the same 404 error. I am using 1.9 jersey and 2.13 jetty.

Comment: You are passing the `ServletContextHandler` to your Jetty Server? Are you seeing your package scanned for annotations at server start?